# cakephp controller had a folder How to use?

Tags: cakephp, controller, routes

This is a folder under  controller  like `wap(index_controller.php)` 
how to use `wap/index` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can study at Config/bootstrap.php, learn it in handbook.